# Gitlab: Cannot push to branch with Owner user

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

We have moved from a GitLab 15.7.3 to a GitLab 15.11.0 installation.

When doing a release, we now encounter this behaviour:

Our Jenkins successfully reads/ clones from the gitlab repo for a build with an SSH key configured inside Jenkins.
However, when doing a release build with the same key to the same repository, we are experiencing this error when pushing back to the repo:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/abc/jenkins/workspace/xy && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-314273937.commit pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /home/abc/jenkins/workspace/xy
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/abc/jenkins/workspace/xy && git symbolic-ref HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /home/abc/jenkins/workspace/xy
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/abc/jenkins/workspace/xy && git push ssh:********@ip:22/group/subgroup/xy refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[INFO] Working directory: /home/abc/jenkins/workspace/xy

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project xy: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] remote:
[ERROR] remote: ========================================================================
[ERROR] remote:
[ERROR] remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
[ERROR] remote:
[ERROR] remote: ========================================================================
[ERROR] remote:
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

To exclude permissions errors, we have already tested

- giving the user Owner permission on the repository
- unprotect all branches

The above error message persists, however.
Apparently, the user is able to connect to the repo correctly, since we're not running into a permission denied message.

We had a similar issue on the previous gitlab installation, over there we made this work by setting `Developer+Maintainer are allowed to push` and giving the user Maintainer permissions on the repo. This does not seem to work on the new installation.

Are there any other permission settings on gitlab that might prevent the user from pushing code?

Comment: Did you check which username is linked to the SSH keys that take effect during the push?

Comment: @ElpieKay Do you mean to check, whether the correct SSH key is added to the respective gitlab user account? I am quite sure that I have the correct key associated with the user's gitlab account. There it also says, that the key has recently been used, which should be the case for the read access/ clone operation.

Comment: The log says `Unable to commit files`. Does the push invoke some hook which fails and prevents the push?

Answer (score 0):

This has finally been resolved by using an SSH Alias from the SSH config as the remote repository URL instead of using a plain url.

This only seems to show Jenkins, which is the exact SSH key to use for authentication and will then go through without problems.

Interesting note in this specific case (Java repo +  Maven) is that Jenkins is not using the same url for pushing as given in the Job configuration (which will only be used for cloning the repo) but will use the `<connection>` as given on the pom.xml/ settings.xml.